# Talking text+images from user and saving it to firebase to display later. (Like quora)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout, kotlin

I'm making a blogging app. I want to make the editor like quora.
User can type post and insert images in between of texts. Then when he clicks save, I want this to get saved in firebase and later retrieve it to display in the same order the user inserted texts and images.
In short,Like quora answers where you can have text and images.

[Like this](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1LkcF5HVWQlYWcO4WNLBtG9YZc9fwdqfi&export=download)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I get your question now.
What you want is a HTML **Rich TextView** including images tags and all.
So for displaying you'd use `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(youHtml))`

and for saving you could use any 3rd party **RichEditText** library it'll give you an html result to save to firebase including images and text is the user's order
some RichEditTexts :- [RichTextEditor](https://github.com/dankito/RichTextEditor), [richeditor-android](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android),
[Android-RTEditor](https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor)

Mark answered if this answers your question

---

---

**This is old answer on how to implement uploading images and get the link for it**
assuming your question is about uploading text and image into Firebase's Firestore
First you'll need to upload the image to firebase storage and get the download URI

```
    // Create a storage reference from our app
   StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
   Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(IMAGE PATH));
   final StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
             // TODO NEXT PART 
        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

and after getting download uri upload both the uri and the textView to Firestore like this

```
Map<String, String> post = new HashMap<>();
user.put("text", myPostEditText.getText().toString());
user.put("image", downloadUri);

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
// Add a new document with a generated ID
db.collection("posts")
        .add(post)
```

so the final code for saving the uploading this should be something like this

```
     // Create a storage reference from our app
     StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
     Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(IMAGE PATH));
        final StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
        uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }

                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                return ref.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    Map<String, String> post = new HashMap<>();
                    user.put("text", myPostEditText.getText().toString());
                    user.put("image", downloadUri);

                    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
// Add a new document with a generated ID
                    db.collection("posts")
                            .add(post).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                        }
                    })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    // Handle failures
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: User can upload multiple images and text. text then image then image then text and so on. and how can I display later then in text view exactly the way it was entered.?

Comment: @sunny52525 sorry the question is not clear enough. what's your problem exactly? do you mean you want to upload a post with multiple images and captions? or you mean multiple posts and the way to retrieve and display them

Comment: I'll edit the question. What I want is like quora. Where I can type something , Upload images too in between answer, then the person who views the published answer , sees exactly in the order I wrote my answer.

Comment: @sunny52525 I get it I will try to update my answer

Comment: Ok,sure. Thank you